# Selecting unique values skips some of them?

Tags: xml, xslt

Right now I am trying to select data from a XML file from a XSL file, keeping all fields unique (so that I don't get multiples of anything). However, while this works, some of the header names think they are sub-header names, of some reason.

**XML code:**

```
<Response>
<Guidelines>
    <Guideline>
        <GuidelineName> Header goes here </GuidelineName>
        <GuidelineSubname> First </GuidelineSubname>
    </Guideline>
    <Guideline>
        <GuidelineName> Header goes here </GuidelineName>
        <GuidelineSubname> Second </GuidelineSubname>
    </Guideline>
    <Guideline>
        <GuidelineName> Header goes here </GuidelineName>
        <GuidelineSubname> Third </GuidelineSubname>
    </Guideline>
</Guidelines>
</Response>
```

**XSL code:**

```
<xsl:for-each select="Response/Guidelines/Guideline">
<h3> <xsl:value-of select="GuidelineName[not(.=preceding::*)]" /> </h3>

<ul>
   <li> <xsl:value-of select="GuidelineSubname" /> </li>
</ul>   

</xsl:for-each>
```

If the preceding command is NOT present, it works, but since it doesn't filter out and make unique headers then it gets quite messy.

**What I want to happen:**

## Header goes here

-First

## Header goes here

-Second

## Header goes here

-Third

**What happens:**

## Header goes here

-Second 
 
-First

So as you see, one of the headers aren't there, causing the subheader to fall under the wrong name.

## Header goes here

-Third

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="Guideline">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="GuidelineName">
  <h3><xsl:apply-templates/></h3>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="GuidelineSubname">
  <ul><li><xsl:apply-templates/></li></ul>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Sorry. I missed that detail by focusing too much on just the input XML and output samples given.